# How to access an array calling a category method within the method itself?

Tags: objective-c, methods

I am new to Objective-C.  I'm trying to create a category method for arrays that doesn't use a parameter.  I'm told there is a way that the method can use this array without using the array as an argument.  I haven't seen much specific to this question.  Can anyone tell me how to access the array calling the method from within the category method?

I know using an argument works. Like this:

```
[array reversed:array];
```

I'm trying to do this instead:

```
[array reversed];
```

Comment: What difficulty are you experiencing?

Comment: Please update your question with your relevant code (as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `array` is not calling anything. It is the object that the `reversed` message is passed to. Within the `-reversed` method, the object being passed the method (`array` in this case) is called `self`, which is how you would access it in a category, or any method  of an object.

In your example, that would look something like:

```
@interface NSArray (Reversed)
- (NSArray *)reversed;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Reversed)

- (NSArray *)reversed {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];

    // Here is where you refer to the target as `self`
    for (id element in [self reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        [result addObject: element];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *xs = @[@1, @2, @3];
        NSArray *reversed = [xs reversed];
        NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", xs, reversed);
    }
    return 0;
}
```